# create an optgroup with cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm novice in cakephp, and i'm having dificulties in something like this:

starting with this sql query:

```
         select service_group.name as service_group_name, service_group.id as service_group_id, campaign.name as campaign_name, campaign.id as campaign_id
      from group_service
      join group_service_campaign on group.service.id = group_service_campaign.group_service_id
      join campaign on group_service_campaign.campaign_id = campaign.id
      where campaign.active = 'Y'
      and campaign.id in ($in)
      and campaign.company_id = ${_SESSION['companyId']}
      order by group_service.name, campaign.name
```

I converted it to this in my controller:

```
$var_campaign = $this->loadModel('Service_Group');
$var_campaign = $this->Group_Service->find('list', ['keyfield' => 'campaign_id', 'valueField' => 'campaign_name', 'groupField' => 'service_group_name'])
            ->join(['table' => 'service_group_campaign',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => 'Service_Group.id = service_group_campaign.service_group_id'
            ])
            ->join(['table' => 'campaign',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => 'service_group_campaign.campaign_id = campaign.id'
    ]);
    $var_campaign->where(['campaign.active' => 'Y']);
    $var_campaign->order(['grou_service.name,campaign.name']);
```

My difficult is to how use this to create an select form element with optgroup.
I've searche for examples and questions similar, but all i tried don't work.

My view:

```
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('label' => 'Services :', 'type' => 'select', 'empty'=> '-- Select --', 'options' => $var_campaign));
echo $this->Form->select("field", $var_campanha);

echo $this->Form->end();
```

When i use find('list' ...) in query statement, i get a blank response, if i use find('all' ...) i get a not complete response, because all campaign names dont come in response, only the services group names with their id's.

My optgroup show a plain text like:

{"id": -1, "name": "Active Proposals","mod": "W","company_id": 10}

and so on.

Where i'm going wrong ?

thanks in advance.